# Knex.js non-terminating functions

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, knex.js

I don't have any problem in this question, I am just interested in how knex.js menaged to something.

In code, you can write something like this

```
let search = knex.table('users').select('something')
if(params.minprice) search.where('minprice', params.minprice)
if(something) search.something()
let result = await search
```

It works, but I don't get how did they menage to hold query execution until await occured? If we did await, it means function was async aka returned a promise. But in javascript, promise executes as soon as function that returned it is called, it does not care is there .then() or .catch(). Should not query execution start al line 1? What is more, when I log search, it is not a promise, but some kind of object, so how can it be awaited?

Can someone provide a simple example how to achieve such a behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `search` contains a property named `then`, which is a function that initiates the search and also behaves similarly to the functionality of `Promise.prototype.then`.

E.g.:

```js
// define Searchable
let Searchable = function() {
  this.searchParam = 'param';
};
Searchable.prototype = {
  setSearchParam: function(p) { this.searchParam = p; },
  initiateSearch: async function() {
    // lots of fancy searching
    console.log(`Searching with param "${this.searchParam}"`);
    return `search based on "${this.searchParam}"`;
  },
  then: async function(callback) {
    // initiate the search:
    let searchResults = await this.initiateSearch();
    
    // behave kind of like `Promise.prototype.then`!
    return callback(searchResults);
  }
};

// now work with it:
(async () => {
  
  let searchable = new Searchable();
  searchable.setSearchParam('mySearchParam');
  
  console.log('No search performed yet!');
  
  // Here's the fancy usage you're concerned with (it invokes `searchable.then`):
  let searchResult = await searchable; 

  console.log('RESULT:', searchResult);
  
})();
```

Calling `await` on some `value` will attempt to call `value.then` as if it were a function accepting a callback argument.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I would have never came up with that. This actually made me laugh.

Answer (score 0):

Knex query builder is mutable and `thenable` object.

So every time you call for example `search.where(...)` for that query builder, its internal state changes and stores that new where clause.

Query builder being thenable means that the object has `.then()` method and when you call `await search` it is actually pretty much equivalent with `await Promise.resolve(search)` which first executes `thenable` and converts it to promise which is then resolved or an exception might occur.

Thenable objects are actually pretty important part of promise spec providing interoperability API between promises and non-promise objects.